# Determining the number of parallel processes in a multi-instance subprocess

Tags: camunda

I am modelling a process which at times will require a very large number of parallel sub-processes (tens of thousands) to be launched. Obviously it’s not possible for these all to run in parallel simultaneously - how will the Camunda process engine handle this? Is it possible to control how many subprocesses will run at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Camunda 7 uses a job executor thread pool. This determines the concurrency level of jobs such an asynchronously started call activity.
The amount of sub processes you mentioned is very high though. What history level did you have in mind? It is likely better to handle this differently.

Camunda 8 was release two days ago. It has a fundamentally different architecture, no relational DB, applying event streaming concepts, designed for massive volumes. It may be more suitable for your use case.